# Game view doesn't match camera preview

Tags: unity-game-engine

I really am not sure what went wrong. I was messing with Unity Networking a little bit and added a Network Identity, Network Manager, Network Manager HUD, and the "Lobby" package, but I've removed them. Somewhere along the way - not exactly sure when - my game view became incorrect.

Here you can see the camera preview and the game view. The game view is just zoomed out a bunch and doesn't respond to any changes I make in the scene view, even when it's playing:

[image]

Here is the camera in the inspector:

[image]

Happy to provide any other info.

Comment: Is there another camera in the scene ?

Comment: Can you try change your camera projection `Orthographic` instead of `Perspective` ?

Comment: Try and set the aspect ratio to something else than Free Aspect.

Comment: I tried orthographic and non-free aspect, it's the same

Comment: @EmreE is there a way to show just cameras in the hierarchy? There is only one I can see, and I don't think there are others but I guess _possibly_ theres one nested deep somewhere or something.

Comment: @EmreE nevermind I see the hierarchy has a search input, and I figured it out. Thanks.

Comment: Glad that worked out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the advice of EmreE, I searched the hierarchy inspector for "Camera":

[image]

This "skp_camera_Last_Saved_SketchUp_View" component was deeply nested, and was included in an asset I imported from the Sketchup 3d warehouse. I've imported a number of Sketchup models before and never encountered one which included a camera, so I didn't think to look for it at first.

Deleting this fixed the issue.

Comment: Nice. I'm having the same issue in my Unity mobile game. It was fine when I last left it; now my game is way zoomed in, even though the Camera Preview shows what it should be. No idea what changed but something did, and I searched and there's no other cameras in the scene. ARGH

Comment: EDIT: Oh for God's sake. It was the "Scale" slider that appears when you hit Play. It was at 1.0x which seemed normal to me. I decided to change it and zoomed all the way out to like .21x and that's what my game should look like (I can see the UI and portrait mode looks right). I dunno, must've gotten changed some how. Maybe I started building the game at .21x? Looks fine when I play on my phone though.